# Excel radar chart color based on cell value

Tags: excel, charts, colors, cell

I have a radar chart that looks like the attached picture. Each radar has a value between 1 and 5. Instead of having a ‘colourful’ chart, I wanted them to be either a red, amber or green colour based on their value (I.e. green if it is 1 or 2, amber of its 3 and red if it’s 4 or 5). It needs to be dynamic such that if the value changes, colour of the chart will also change.

Any thoughts of ideas on this will be really appreciated! Many thanks.

[image]

Comment: My guess is you'll need VBA for this.

Comment: Indeed @BigBen. However, have not been able to figure out the code for that and how to call it such that it automatically updates the chart. Any ideas will be very helpful!

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of some sample data or your setup?